# XMLWriterSettings NewLineOnAttributes property has no effect

Tags: .net, xml

I have this code to write a simple XML file

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("file.xml", settings);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

writer.WriteStartElement("book");
writer.WriteAttributeString("genre", "Mystery");
writer.WriteAttributeString("publicationdate", "2001");
writer.WriteAttributeString("ISBN", "123456789");
writer.WriteElementString("title", "Case of the Missing Cookie");
writer.WriteStartElement("author");
writer.WriteElementString("name", "Cookie Monster");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteElementString("price", "9.99");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
//clean up
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

but it has no effect on the output, all the attributes on the same line,
according to MSDN, the only catch to use this property is having the `Indent` property set to true.
and I already did that, and still no use.
Googling came back with nothing.

I'm using C# in visual studio 2012 with  .net 4.5

Comment: Same here, if you find something please post it here.

Comment: glad to know I'm not alone :)

Comment: Actually in my case it seems to work but not for all the attributes, i have 6 attributes of which 3 are in a new line... seems very strange...